# SCSS sum of two rem units added together outputs the operation not the value

Tags: sass

I am attempting to subtract the value of two rem units form a margin in scss however the css outputs the operation instead of the value. Is this even possible?

I have a rem value and a pixel value which I use a function to convert to rem then try to subtract the sum of them added together. Thanks for some help

```
$size-md: 1.25rem;
$border-md: 2px;

@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16px;
  @return #{$remSize}rem;
}

p {
  margin-right: - (#{$size-md} + #{calculateRem($border-md)});
```

**CSS Output**

```
p { margin-right: 1.25rem + 0.125rem; }
```

Sassmeister Code

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3d3456752f0d82071e75e1afb54ab7f5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue is the string interpolation using `#{$variable}`.

Once something is interpolated into a string, that is how the sass compiler will continue to treat it.

There area few options:

#### 1. Wrap the string calculation with `calc()` and allow the browser to just add the two numbers.

Input:

```
p { margin-right: calc(#{$size-md} + #{calculateRem($border-md)});
```

Output:

```
p { margin-right: calc(1.25rem + 0.125rem); }
```

#### 2. Use a custom sass function to convert the string back to numbers.

Refer to https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/01/15/sass-string-to-number/

Input:

```
p { margin-right: (number($size-md) + number(calculateRem($border-md)));
```

Output:

```
p { margin-right: 1.375rem; }
```

#### 3. Remove the string interpolation

Input:

```
@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16px;
  @return $remSize * 1rem; // removed string interpolation, use * 1rem to convert to rems
}

p { margin-right: ($size-md + calculateRem($border-md)); // removed string interpolation to allow number calculations
```

Output:

```
p { margin-right: 1.375rem; }
```

I think #3 is the best option, but it will depend on your codebase.